# JTable doesn't refresh after adding new row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh

I have a JTable inside a JScrollPane. After calling my function which should populate the table I can't see any changes! I'v tried with `table.repaint()`, `model.fireTableDataChanged()` and probably some other stuff that I can't remember anymore - nothing worked. What am I doing wrong??

My function:

```
public static void fillVodicTable(JTable table){

    DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(); //also tried (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    table.setModel(model);
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Ime", "Priimek", "Epošta", "Datum rojstva", "Licenca", "Jeziki"});
    String [] row={"a","b","c","d","e","f"};

    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) there no reason call for `model.fireTableDataChanged()` for `DefaultTableModel`

2) there no reason call for `table.repaint()`, is useless

3) what's `for(Jezik j : v.getTuji_jeziki()) row[5]+=", "+j.toString();` there could be more than 100% **** of your issues

4) `DefaultTableModel` works in all cases, but requierd only update on EDT, in other hands this is common issue for all Swing JComponents together

5) for better help sooner edit yout question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

6) EDT == [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

7) SSCCE

- DefaultTableModel
- model.addRow(row);
- Short
- Self Contained
- Correct
- Example

then

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class DefaultTableModelDemo {

    public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"
    };
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMN_NAMES, 0);
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private Random random = new Random();

    public DefaultTableModelDemo() {
        JButton addDataButton = new JButton("Add Data");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(addDataButton);
        addDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addDataActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        model = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMN_NAMES, 0) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }

                return c;
            }
        };
        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void addDataActionPerformed() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Object[] row = new Object[COLUMN_NAMES.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                row[j] = random.nextInt(5);
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("DefaultTableModelDemo");
                frame.getContentPane().add(new DefaultTableModelDemo().getComponent());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my example to be SSCCE compiant. Also, tried this with my app and there is no difference. Also, what do you mean by EDT?

Comment: drugs and alcohol are really bad, sure only in small quantities, can downvoter share your reason

Comment: I did not down vote you - I am grateful for your response. What I found out, Sir, is that I was plain stupid. I called this function with wrong argument (wrong table)! So now it's working the way it was - but I have to switch a tab to see the changes. I guess I should repaint something afterall (but not table, it doesn't help as you said before).

Comment: I think that swithing to the daylight saving time in continental EU

Comment: Maybe :) Do you have any clue how to repaint without tab switching (I have CardLayout)?

Answer (score 1):

I know its old but, i had the same problem and the solution was to add

```
jTable1.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(true);
```

Comment: I don't have the application at the hand currently so I can't test but maybe it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

1.To populate jtable data:

```
void update_table() throws SQLException {
   rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from details");
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}
```

2. Then call the update function to buttons action event and refresh the jtable

And for more information you can view this tutorial:
[How to refresh JTable after insert delete or update the data in java Netbeans ID](http://tut.julfi.com/refresh-jtable-insert-delete-update-data-java-netbeans-id/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I recently had the same problem and the solution was to call

```
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

right after adding the new row to the model.

The catch was this: I had a table on which I allowed sorting. Without clicking the column headers so that the rows would sort accordingly, I was able to add data to the model and see the changes in the table by calling `table.revalidate();` However, if, at any time, I clicked the column headers, any row added afterwards wouldn't be shown, although the model data was updating properly. By only calling `model.fireTableDataChanged();` after adding the data to the model, it works as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have made a new project in that I have selected a new frame and drag a table, a label, a text field and a button from the swing controls to your frame.

2.create a table in back-end…

3. Download rs2xml jar file from this link

[Download rs2xml.jar](http://fvmproject.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9/trunk/rs2xml.jar)

4. Add it to the project library…

Right click on the project > properties > library > add Jar/folder > select jar > ok

5.Then connect mysql  using following code

```
public class DBConnect {

Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
        System.out.println("connection successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
}
```

6. Call the function in the page using following code

   ```
   con=new DBConnect();
   statement=con.getConnection().createStatement();
   ```

7.Then create a update function type the following code…

```
void update_table() throws SQLException{
    rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from details");
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

8.In the buttons action event type the following and call the update function

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   try {
       Object name=jTextField1.getText();
       String sql="insert into details (name) values('"+name+"')";
        int  resultset=statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        update_table();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(update.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

}

9.Then run the project…

YOU can also Follow this Tutorial:--

[How to refresh JTable after insert delete or update the data in java Netbeans ID](http://tut.julfi.com/refresh-jtable-insert-delete-update-data-java-netbeans-id/)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
class JTableDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

JTable jt;
DefaultTableModel model;
JButton btn;
String[] cols={"Dno","DName","Loc"};
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

public JTableDemo()
{
    model=new DefaultTableModel(cols,0);
    btn=new JButton("Add Record");
    btn.addActionListener(this);
    jt=new JTable(model);
    btn.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 40);
    mainPanel.setBounds(10,200,300,200);
    add(btn);
    mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(jt));
    add(mainPanel);
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(500, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
public JComponent getComponent() {
    return mainPanel;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object[] row = new Object[3];
    row[0]="10";
    row[1]="SW";
    row[2]="PKL";
    model.addRow(row);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new JTableDemo();
}
```

}

[image: See Some Records]