# Jtable - getvalueAt() issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I want to know why my `getvalueAt()` is picking old data when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.
I tried all update and table change modules, but I couldn't get it working. I am making an Excel sheet-like structure in `JTable`, in which one row updates on change to another row.

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        if(column == 2 || column == 3 || column == 4 || column == 5)
    {
        System.out.println("2 is: "+getValueAt(row, 2));
        System.out.println("3 is: "+getValueAt(row, 3));
        System.out.println("4 is: "+getValueAt(row, 4));
        long closingbalance = Long.parseLong(getValueAt(row,2).toString())
            + Long.parseLong(getValueAt(row,3).toString())
            - Long.parseLong(getValueAt(row,4).toString());
        System.out.println("closing: "+closingbalance);
        super.setValueAt(closingbalance,row, 6);
    }               
    super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
}
```

Comment: Please follow this guide lines before writing some question next time http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.
And please, please, stop the ellipsis Morse Code writing where a single dot is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be able to answering your question on another forum, because a new forums version driving me crazy

- there no reason parsing value from `JTable`,
- `JTable` implemets all important data types
- examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863996/714968) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709633/714968)
- for better help edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: +1 for the [default renderer/editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) data types.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your `CellEditor` has concluded and that your `TableModel` is in a consistent state when you access other values. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) override's `getValueAt()` to derive the dependent cell's value. To avoid so much parsing, your `TableModel` should probably just contain instances of `Long`.

Assuming you really need to override `setValueAt()`, it's not clear what `TableModel` you're using. If you're extending `DefaultTableModel`, the `super.setValueAt()` implementation is appropriate; if you're extending `AbstractTableModel`, the super implementation is empty, and yours will need to fire the appropriate event.